# Generics Resolve into Intersection Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, set-intersection

Why `typeof` `body` is resolve as Intersection Type `SignRequest & {}`.

```js
export interface HttpResponse<T> {
  statusCode: number;
  body: T | Error;
}

export interface HttpRequest<T> {
  body?: T;
}

export interface Controller {
  handle<T>(httpRequest: HttpRequest<T>): HttpResponse<T>;
}

export class SignUpController implements Controller {
  handle<SignRequest>(httpRequest: HttpRequest<SignRequest>): HttpResponse<SignRequest> {

    if (httpRequest.body === null || httpRequest.body === undefined) {
      throw new Error("Bad Request")
    }

    // **issue here**
    const body = httpRequest.body; // body: SignRequest & {}

    if (body !== null && body !== undefined){
      console.log(body.name) // Error: Any: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SignRequest & {}'
    }

    throw new Error("Not implemented exception");
  }
}

export interface SignRequest {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirmation: string;
}
```

Any tips in how to access `body.name` in a more idiomatic way?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#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)

Comment: I'm not sure why `handle` is generic. Why not [this](https://tsplay.dev/weQoaw)?

Comment: @caTS, certainly this is a solution, but would be better to understand more how the languages works in this scenario.

Comment: This is caused by a generic addition of `T` from `Controller`. The controller extends the type of `httpRequest` to `any` and as such the error. About why you are getting `& {}`; it is because TS uses `{}` as any non-null object.

Comment: @Akxe, awesome, why adding this  overload ``handle<TRequest, Response> ...`` make the compiler happy? [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGAjXN). The code only works if we have both overloads.

Comment: @Cássio, to be honest, this is borderline for a bug report. Since uncommenting either variant of overloads breaks the code, that clearly does not have to be broken... I would say I do have a lot of experience with TS, but it is beyond me why this workaround fixes it...

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `handle` itself to be generic, but the interface `Controller` itself:

```
export interface Controller<T> {
  handle(httpRequest: HttpRequest<T>): HttpResponse<T>;
}
```

Then when you implement this interface, you would pass in the desired type:

```
export class SignUpController implements Controller<SignRequest> {
```

Now the signature of `handle` looks like:

```
handle(httpRequest: HttpRequest<SignRequest>): HttpResponse<SignRequest> {
```

and also `body` is now of type `SignRequest`:

```
    if (body !== null && body !== undefined){
      console.log(body.name) // OK
    }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQoaw)

Comment: Awesome, @caTS, certainly this a workaround. But this [message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74265542/generics-resolve-into-intersection-type#comment131116988_74265542) also works.  It is possible to figure out why using overload works the same why using an Interface Type Parameter?

Comment: @Cássio `handle` is then to be implicitly inferred as `handle<SignRequest, SignRequest>`.

Comment: Okay, @caTS,  but removing ``Controller.handle<T>(httpRequest: HttpRequest<T>)`` causes compilation error. [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0njGw). Why we need two overloads, why with two overloads we have the same compiler behavior, as using  an Interface Type Parameter?

Comment: Hm, I actually don't know this one. I've seen duplicate overloads being required to satisfy the compiler, but not this. You should probably ask another question on the site about this.